# How to write module specific logs file in websphere which contains multiple web module

Tags: java, websphere

I have Enterprise Application which contains the multiple web applications.My requirement is to have the web module specific logs file.I am using IBM websphere server.We can do it server specific like below but i want it application level.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/reB10.png)